# How do I set up a New Connection for a personal-use Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install SQL Developer on my personal computer so I can practice and improve my SQL skills. I installed SQL Developer 19.1 with JDK 8 included and everything seem to work fine. However, when I try adding a new connection, I have no clue where to find a username/password or what kind of connection type to use. Does anyone have any documentation or know how to setup an oracle database for personal use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[So I downloaded Oracle SQL Developer...now what?](https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303)

download a vm, download a docker template, or download oracle XE installer and create a new database running on your laptop.

The VM ([oracle virtualbox appliance](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html)) is IMO, the easiest way to get started.

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. I'm having issues starting the box. When I start the virtual box, I get an error that says the.ova appliance could not be imported, even though I see it under the Tools section. Also, when i get into the virtual box, I get a message that says "Kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu".

Comment: sounds like hardware virtualization is disabled in your machine's BIOS - that needs to be turned on